# How to prevent react native from re-rendering the whole list state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm developing a Tetris like game using react native + Expo. The app consist a large grid, where the color of each square is determined by a 2D list.

[image]

I want to update some values of the 2D list at constant time interval (e.g. 1sec). However I found that the whole grid re-render when only some values of the 2D list were changed. The app works fine in web browser but it suffers from extremely poor performance in the Android emulator and physical devices.

The number of re-rendering is logged.

[image]

Here is the code that I wrote

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback, } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';

class Block {
  orientation: number[][];
  currCoord: number[];
  constructor(orientation: number[][], initCoord: number[]) {
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.currCoord = initCoord;
  }

  canTranslate(grid: number[][], currCoord: number[][]) {
    for (let p of currCoord) {
      if (p[0] >= grid.length) {
        console.log(p[0], p[1], grid.length);
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  drop(tetrisGrid: number[][]) {
    let newCoord = [...this.currCoord];
    newCoord[0]++;

    let tetrisGridClone = tetrisGrid.map((row) => { return [...row] })

    // remove old
    for (let p of this.orientation) {
      tetrisGridClone[this.currCoord[0] + p[0]][this.currCoord[1] + p[1]] = 0;
    }

    let points = []
    for (let p of this.orientation) {
      points.push([newCoord[0] + p[0], newCoord[1] + p[1]])
    }

    if (!this.canTranslate(tetrisGridClone, points)) {
      return null;
    }

    // draw new 
    for (let p of points) {
      tetrisGridClone[p[0]][p[1]] = 1;
    }

    this.currCoord = newCoord;
    return tetrisGridClone;
  }
}


const speed = 1000
const tetrisGridInit: number[][] = []
var nextBlock: Block;
const w = 50;
const h = 50;


export default function App() {
  const [tetrisGridMine, setTetrisGrid] = useState<number[][]>(tetrisGridInit);

  useEffect(() => {
    var grid1 = create2dArray(w, h);
    setTetrisGrid(grid1);
  }, []);

  const startGame = useCallback(() => {
    generateNextBlock();
    setInterval(() => {
      tick();
    }, speed)
  }, []);

  const create2dArray = (width: number, height: number) => {
    var grid = [];
    var row = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        row.push(0);
      }
      grid.push(row);
      row = [];
    }
    return grid;
  }

  const tick = () => {
    console.log("tick")
    setTetrisGrid(tetrisGridMine => {
      let tetrisGridClone = nextBlock.drop(tetrisGridMine);
      if (!tetrisGridClone) {
        console.log("cannot drop")
        return tetrisGridMine;
      }
      return tetrisGridClone;
    })
  }

  const generateNextBlock = () => {
    nextBlock = new Block(
      [[-1, 1], [-1, 0], [0, 0], [0, -1]],
      [1, w / 2]
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-around', margin: 10 }}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

          <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 35, alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'column' }}>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={startGame} >
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, fontWeight: '500', margin: 5, borderWidth: 3, }}>
                {'START'}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
              {
                tetrisGridMine.map((row: number[], i: number) => {
                  return (
                    <View key={i} style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                      {row.map((cell, j) => {

                        console.log("cell");
                        return (
                          <TouchableOpacity key={j} >
                            <View style={[{
                              borderColor: 'black',
                              backgroundColor: cell == 0 ? "white" : "blue",
                              width: 15,
                              height: 15,
                              borderWidth: 1
                            }]}>
                            </View>
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                        )
                      })}
                    </View>
                  )
                })
              }
            </View>
          </View>

        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I'm new to React and React Native. Any advice or help is much appreciated.